# Export Complete MySQL DB Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, export

I am exporting mysql db using a PHP class found on github.. My Issue is, The SQL file created by PHP script has the size of 110KB , AND if I export DB from phpmyadmin it creates file of 125kb. Means my php class is not exporting the complete database. I am looking for more reliable class, please help. Thanks in advance

here is my class:

```
<?php
// EXAMPLE:   EXPORT_TABLES("localhost","user","pass","db_name" ); 
        //optional: 5th parameter - to backup specific tables only: array("mytable1","mytable2",...)   
        //optional: 6th parameter - backup filename
        // IMPORTANT NOTE for people who try to change strings in SQL FILE before importing, MUST READ:  goo.gl/2fZDQL

// https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts  
function EXPORT_TABLES($host,$user,$pass,$name,       $tables=false, $backup_name=false){ 
    set_time_limit(3000); $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name); $mysqli->select_db($name); $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $queryTables = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES'); while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) { $target_tables[] = $row[0]; }   if($tables !== false) { $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables); } 
    $content = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\";\r\nSET time_zone = \"+00:00\";\r\n\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\r\n/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\r\n--\r\n-- Database: `".$name."`\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n";
    foreach($target_tables as $table){
        if (empty($table)){ continue; } 
        $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'`');     $fields_amount=$result->field_count;  $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;     $res = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table); $TableMLine=$res->fetch_row(); 
        $content .= "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";   $TableMLine[1]=str_ireplace('CREATE TABLE `','CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `',$TableMLine[1]);
        for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_row())  { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  {$content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";}
                    $content .= "\n(";    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++){ $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) ); if (isset($row[$j])){$content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;}  else{$content .= '""';}     if ($j<($fields_amount-1)){$content.= ',';}   }        $content .=")";
                //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) {$content .= ";";} else {$content .= ",";} $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
            }
        } $content .="\n\n\n";
    }
    $content .= "\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;";
    $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.'___('.date('H-i-s').'_'.date('d-m-Y').').sql';
    ob_get_clean(); header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");  header('Content-Length: '. (function_exists('mb_strlen') ? mb_strlen($content, '8bit'): strlen($content)) );    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\""); 
    echo $content; exit;
}      //see import.php too

$result = EXPORT_TABLES("localhost","root","","filtration" ); 

if($result){
    header("location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure something is missing. I would actually check before jumping ship

Comment: Yes.. there is missing data

Comment: It probably just means that they export by creating different code. For instance, if I use SQLyog and phpMyAdmin to create export SQL, it's way different and SQLyog's export is way larger, but it's because SQLyog creates individual inserts, and phpMyAdmin does not. If you really want to do it right, use mysqldump on the command line. I say that because you will get to a point where PHP will no longer be able to handle the export if your database gets too big.

Comment: "Looking for a more reliable class" makes your question off-topic. We don't handle software recommendations.

Comment: I am doing this for a client.. was thinking to give him the feature to export db using php

Comment: #Don't Panic.. I have posted my code, if you could make it more reliable..my question will be answered :)

Comment: What is the operating system of the server, Linux? Is the exec function prohibited?

Comment: How do you know it's missing data? How the export is formatted could easily account for the difference in data size.

Comment: Also, I'd be surprised if anyone bothers reading your code. It's indented, which is better than some, but you have few comments and no white space.

Comment: If you are on a Linux server and not opposed to the best solution (does not use any PHP class) I will answer the question.

Comment: I've seen some obfuscated code that looks more readable; anyway you cannot compare using file-size as phpmyadmin add a lot of comments & they add field names while you're using `insert into table values` ... and the first `for` loop is useless; create a counter manually instead

Answer (score 0):

Problems may occur:

- Class won't work well.
- The file phpmyadmin exports has more unusable character like comments.
- php.ini does not let to php for saving file more than a limit size.